# Which Gradle file do I update?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm reading about an Android helper class on GitHub called [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)
and it instructs to add a dependency to the Gradle file in my project.

The problem is, my project has two Gradle files. It has one directly under the main project directory and also one under the app directory, like so:

```
MyProj
|__ app -
|    |__ build +
|    |__ libs +
|    |__ src +
|    |__ build.gradle
|__ build +
|__ gradle +
|__ media +
|__ build.gradle
```

As you can see, there are two `build.gradle`s.

Which one do I update in this case, and more generally, which one gets updated for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one inside app folder.

The dependency entry downloads the latest library, and gets included in your project.

Comment: Can you explain, why this one and not the outside one?

Comment: Not sure "why", but the app folder tree contains the android main project. And I also used Android Studio, and everytime I generate a project from the wizards, the "include" libraries are placed here, so it lead me to conclude that additional libraries should be added here as well.